# can't connect websocket django channels

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

(index):28 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/niwera/stories/1/' failed:

when im in http://127.0.0.1:8000/niwera/stories/ and i click "entrar na história (join story)" this error appears in my dev tools console, but python django terminal return 200/300.

here is my codes:

## ASGI:

```
import os
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
import niwera_rpg.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'niwera.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": URLRouter(niwera_rpg.routing.websocket_urlpatterns)
})
```

## settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'niwera_rpg',
    'channels'
]

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('localhost', 6379)],
        },
        'ROUTING': 'niwera_rpg.routing.channel_routing',
    },
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'niwera.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'niwera.wsgi.application'
```

## urls.py (project)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('niwera/', include('niwera_rpg.urls'))
]
```

## stories.html

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Histórias Disponíveis:</h1>
        {% for story in stories %}
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ story.title }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ story.description }}</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="joinStory({{ story.id }})">Entrar na História</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <script>
        function joinStory(storyId) {
            console.log(`Joining story ${storyId}...`);
            const socket = new WebSocket(
                `ws://${window.location.host}/niwera/stories/${storyId}/`);

            socket.onopen = function (event) {
                console.log('WebSocket connection opened.');
                const data = {
                    action: 'join_story',
                    player_id: 'player123'
                };
                socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
            };

            socket.onmessage = function (event) {
                const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
                console.log(data);
            };

            socket.onclose = function (event) {
                console.log('WebSocket connection closed.');
            };
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

## story_detail.html

```
<div class="container">
        <h1>Detalhes da História</h1>
        <h2>{{ story_data.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ story_data.description }}</p>

        <h2>Personagens Conectados</h2>
        <ul>
            {% for character in connected_characters %}
            <li>{{ character.name }} - HP: {{ character.hp }} - XP: {{ character.xp }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
```

## consumers.py

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer


class StoryConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        print('Conectado')
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        print('Desconectado')
        pass

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        print(data)
        print('Recebido')
        action = data.get('action')

        if action == 'join_story':
            story_id = data.get('story_id')

            response_data = {
                'action': 'join_story',
                'story_id': story_id,
                'story_data': {...},  
                'connected_characters': [...],
            }
            await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(response_data))
```

## routing.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .consumers import StoryConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('/ws/stories/<int:story_id>/', StoryConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

## urls.py from app

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('stories/', views.stories, name='stories'),
    path('stories/<int:story_id>/',
         views.story_details, name='story_details'),
]
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Story


def stories(request):

    stories = Story.objects.all()

    context = {
        'stories': stories
    }
    return render(request, 'stories.html', context)


def story_details(request, story_id):
    story_data = {...} 
    connected_characters = [...] 

    return render(request, 'story_details.html', {'story_data': story_data, 'connected_characters': connected_characters})
```

i tried so much things, i hope that when i click on the button to join a story, it will take me to another route containing the information from "story_details.html"

Comment: I believe in settings your WSGI_APPLICATION needs to be changed to ASGI_APPLICATION.  Been a while since I've done this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.